# React: Update className of this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a component where I'd like to update the className prop of `this.props.children`.

To accomplish this I'm using the `React.Children` utilities. `React.Children.map(children)` to create a new array from the children and `React.cloneElement(child)` to manipulate the child props.

The `map` and `cloneElement` work in some ways. I can add `props` and change the `children` of the individual elements. But `props.className` is not propagated to the `class` of the child when rendered. That is, I see the update to `props.className` in the new children array, but the rendered children don't contain the new `props.className`.

Is this the incorrect way to update `props.className` for `this.props.children`? If so, what is the correct method?

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.items = React.Children.map(this.props.children, item => {
      const className = `${item.props.className} test`;
      const props = { ...item.props, className: className };
      return React.cloneElement(item, props, "TEST");
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.items);
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.items}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className="item">
        {this.props.children}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem ref="item1" className="item">A</ListItem>
        <ListItem ref="item2" className="item">B</ListItem>
        <ListItem ref="item3" className="item">C</ListItem>
        <ListItem ref="item4" className="item">D</ListItem>
      </List>
    );
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's propagated... You're just not using it.

convert

`<li className="item">`

to

`<li className={this.props.className}>`

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.items = React.Children.map(this.props.children, item => {
      const className = `${item.props.className} test`;
      const props = { ...item.props, className: className };
      return React.cloneElement(item, props, "TEST");
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.items}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class ListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li className={this.props.className}>
        {this.props.children}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem ref="item1" className="item">A</ListItem>
        <ListItem ref="item2" className="item">B</ListItem>
        <ListItem ref="item3" className="item">C</ListItem>
        <ListItem ref="item4" className="item">D</ListItem>
      </List>
    );
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.test{
  background-color: red
}

.test {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking it easy on me in pointing out what should have been an obvious mistake.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Sometimes, we solve the hardest problems to only miss out on the easy problems because we overthink it ^^